# Add an element with many parameters in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add an element with many parameter using jQuery?

I've tried the following but did not succeed:

```
var appendNewStoredFile = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-bind="event: {click: function (){ LoadQuery(viewModel,';
appendNewStoredFile += fileName;
appendNewStoredFile += ',';
appendNewStoredFile += TypesOutput
appendNewStoredFile += ',';
appendNewStoredFile += '1';
appendNewStoredFile += ');}}" class="list-group-item ItemInList" style="background-color: beige"><span style="margin: 0 5px">';
appendNewStoredFile += fileName;
appendNewStoredFile += '</span></a>';
$('#StoredQuery').append(appendNewStoredFile);
```

Output:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" 
   data-bind="event: {click: function (){ LoadQuery(viewModel,Test-Error,T_Motors,1);}}" 
   class="list-group-item ItemInList" style="background-color: beige">
  <span style="margin: 0 5px">Test-Error</span>
</a>
```

Parameters are not included in quotation. I want be like:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" 
   data-bind="event: {click: function () { LoadQuery(viewModel,'Test-Error','T_Motors',1);}}" 
   class="list-group-item ItemInList" 
   style="background-color: beige">
  <span style="margin: 0 5px">Test-Error</span>
</a>
```

Comment: are you using any other framework like backbone

Comment: I don't know, but i would try this: `LoadQuery(this)` and then after adding the element, select it and `$(element).data("file-name", fileName);` and for the others parameters. Inside the function, access it by `data()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using jQuery you can pass an object to it instead of using string concatenation:

```
$('<a/>', {
    // setting attributes
    href: "#",
    "class": "whatever",
    foo: "bar",
    // setting data-* properties:
    // if you want to store the datum as an attribute and not a property 
    // use `data-*` instead of using `data` object
    // `data` object is set by `.data()` method 
    // and `data-*` property is set by `.attr()` method 
    data: {
       bind: { foo: 'bar' }
    },
    'data-bind': "value",
    // setting html content
    html: '<element>...</element>',
    // event handling
    click: function(e) {
      // e.preventDefault();
    },
    // setting styles
    css: { color: 'red' } 
}).appendTo('#StoredQuery');
```

Comment: not the same markup as requested by the OP... can be changed to http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8jHVD/1/ .... because from the looks of it the `data-bind` attribute might be used by some other library

Answer (score 0):

You will need to wrap your variables with `'`

```
        appendNewStoredFile += '\''+ fileName + '\'',
        appendNewStoredFile += '\''+ TypesOutput + '\''
```

---

But there is a better way to approach dynamic DOM element creation..

```
$('<a>',{
   click: function(){ loadQuery(viewModel, filename, TypesOutput,1);},
   'class': 'list-group-item ItemInList',
   css: {color:'beige'},
   html: $('<span>',{
             css: {margin: '0 5px'},
             text: filename
         })
}).appendTo('#StoredQuery');
```